# why we do not use '&' in scanf for char arrray

Tags: c, pointers

```
int age;
char name[10];

scanf("%d", &age);
scanf("%s", name);
```

In first `scanf` function we use `'&'` symbol before age, but in second `scanf` we don't use `'&'`
as it is a char array. Can anybody tell me why is so?

Comment: @AVD: Please don't mod-flag a recent question you already VTC'd. Community votes are perfectly fine for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to ("decay") to type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

When you write

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

the expression `name` has type "10-element array of `char`"; by the rule above, it is converted to type "pointer to `char`", and its value is the same as `&name[0]`.  So `scanf` receives a pointer value, not an array value.

The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression is an operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration.

Note that the expressions `name` and `&name` will give you the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array), but their types will be different; `name` will have type `char *`, while `&name` will have type `char(*)[10]`, or "pointer to 10-element array of `char`".

Answer (score 5):

Because the array is already passed as an address, whereas the integer variable is not (and thus explicitly needs its address passed via the `&` address-of operator).

Answer (score 4):

An array name by itself references the beginning of that array in memory. In this case:

```
name == &name[0]
```